# Creating a Search on AngulaJs: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a search on AngularJs based on the snippet I found on codepen and this is the URL http://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/AmGcg

This is a snippet on what I have tried

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Example">
  <div class="container controls">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <form action="" method="POST" role="form">
                  <legend>Find a movie from <a href="http://yousee.tv/film">YouBio</a></legend>
                  <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control" ng-model="search">
                      <div class="input-group-addon">Found {{(movies | filter:search).length}} of {{movies.length}}</div> 
      <div class="input-group-addon "><input type="checkbox" ng-model="reverse" value="true" id="reverse" /><label for="reverse">Reverse</label></div>
      <div class="input-group-addon "><input type="checkbox" ng-model="list" value="true" id="reverse" /><label for="list">List</label></div>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

This is JS file:

```
angular.module("myApp",["ngSanitize"])
.filter('replace', function () {
    var pat = / /gi;
    return function (text) {
        var clean = text.replace(pat, "-");
        var temp = clean.split("---");
        if (temp.length>1) {
          clean = temp[0];
        }
        return clean;
    };
})
.controller("Example", function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.search = "orig";
  $scope.movies = youMovie;
  $scope.reverse = false;
  $scope.list = false;
});
```

And I am getting the following the error
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
On my Chrome Console

And here is a plunk I have made
http://plnkr.co/edit/00ghGQtBKkvEKkzlD52c?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I made some modifications and the code is working now.

HMTL markup, by the way there were lots of miskes.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.1.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.1.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script> -->



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="col-md-12">AngularJS <code>ng-repeat</code> with search</h1>
    <blockquote>AngularJS lets you easily do a <em>instant search</em> if you say save your data as <code>JSON</code>. The elegant way that it is coded and the performance I find great. The <code>JSON</code> data I use, I have collected from Danish streaming TV service <a href="http://yousee.tv/film">YouBio</a>. I use <code>bootstrap 3</code> to control the markup/layout. <br />
      <code>2014/11/14</code> Added link to watch the movie on YouSee Play (not free).</blockquote>
</div>
</div>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Example">
  <div class="container controls">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <form action="" method="POST" role="form">
                  <legend>Find a movie from <a href="http://yousee.tv/film">YouBio</a></legend>
                  <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control" ng-model="search">
                      <div class="input-group-addon">Found {{(movies | filter:search).length}} of {{movies.length}}</div> 
      <div class="input-group-addon "><input type="checkbox" ng-model="reverse" value="true" id="reverse" /><label for="reverse">Reverse</label></div>
      <div class="input-group-addon "><input type="checkbox" ng-model="list" value="true" id="reverse" /><label for="list">List</label></div>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container result">
      <div ng-class="list ? 'col-md-6' : 'col-md-4'" class="movie" ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter:search | orderBy:'title':reverse"> <a href="https://film.youseeplay.dk/search/{{movie.title}}" target="_blank">
          <img ng-class="list ? 'col-md-2' : 'col-md-12'" ng-src="{{movie.src}}" alt="Click to play {{movie.title}} on YouSee Play (not free)" title="Click to play {{movie.title}} on YouSee Play (not free)" class="img-thumbnail" /></a>
          <h4 ng-class="list ? 'col-md-10' : 'col-md-12'">{{movie.title}}</h4> 
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<body>
</html>
```

Controller, also you did't have and data to present in the view so I added some dummy data:

```
angular.module("myApp",["ngSanitize"])
.filter('replace', function () {
    var pat = / /gi;
    return function (text) {
        var clean = text.replace(pat, "-");
        var temp = clean.split("---");
        if (temp.length>1) {
          clean = temp[0];
        }
        return clean;
    };
})
.controller('Example', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('search', function(newVal, oldVal) {
      $scope.search = newVal;
      $scope.movies = [{title: 'Movie 1'}, {title: 'Movie 2'}, {title: 'Movie 3'}, {title: 'Moive 4'}, {title: 'Movie 5'}];
      $scope.reverse = false;
      $scope.list = false;
   });
  }
]);
//document.querySelector('#search').focus();
```

Comment: Am checking the solution.

Comment: Please create a plunk for this answer.

Comment: You don't have data, only thing I could do is to create some dummy data with title.

Comment: I understand.... Check the codepen demo and make a plunk of your answer accordingly....

Answer (score 0):

You are injecting a module you have not loaded on the page.  The ngSantize module is standalone from the angular.min.js source.  You need to load `angular-sanitize.min.js` on the page.

Comment: The file has been added on the plunk. You can take a look.

Comment: You have a syntax issue.  This is what I see - <script src"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>.  You are missing "=" after the src attribute

Comment: Sure! I see it now. The code snippet seems not be complete from codepen

Comment: So the author snuck in an external js file into the codepen. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3260327/youMovie.js.  This is one the faults I have with codepen.io is that some of the dependencies are hidden.  With plunkr, they are visible :)

Comment: Please accept if this helped :) Working on Stackoverflow score :)

Answer (score 0):

you not load santize file like:

Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.1.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>

//** This file add***
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<script src="app.js"></script>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
```

Comment: Sorry. Please can you be more explicit.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionic/1.1.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>

**This file add**
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<script src="app.js"></script>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Still the same result!

Comment: see this plunker [Plunker Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/aTIDACOfPl2bMFqxwwVV?p=preview)